# Creating a wifi hotspot from my PC

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, usb, modem

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit on my Desktop PC. Also, I am using a USB
Modem which doesn't have any router.

I'm happy with my current speed and connection but recently I bought a new
smartphone and decided to use Internet on that too (you know play store
and ....).

In our country mobile Internet is too costly so I thought about
creating a wifi hotspot from my PC and use that in my smartphone but
after seeing almost all the tutorials and software I couldn't do it.
See the pictures and details below and you might get an idea about my PC:

http://tny.cz/51126940

I'm using the following service for Internet : http://www.banglalionwimax.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying this tutorial: [How to Turn Your Windows 8 Laptop into a Wireless Access Point](http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/). If I'm not mistaken it works on Winodws 7 as well. Granted your WLan card supports it.

If you don't want to get too technical you can always try [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/). It's pretty much just a nice GUI to do everything in the tutorial above.

Comment: Sorry but I've tried all kind of tuts and software

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if your laptop's built in WiFi Card doesn't support broadcasting as an Access Point, you can buy a USB Wifi stick that uses a RT5370 chipset. A cheap one off ebay comes with the software to make the USB WiFi stick work as an AP, and is rather easy to use too.

Comment: Will this work : m.alibaba.com/product/643051604/150Mbps_USB_WiFi_Dongle_WiFi_Dongle.html

Do I need anything else than an adapter?

Comment: That one should work fine. That's the same as the one I used on Windows 7 to create an AP